# Displaying multiple paragraphs from a text content in a SQL server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have a column in my SQL server that contains a long string of text. (PAGE_CONTENT) I am able to display it in my website except it is displaying just like it is in the SQL server table...one huge paragraph...Not fun at all to read :( My original design has this content broken with `<br/>` tags....So, my question is, if I need the output in paragraphs, do I need to make a bunch of PAGE_CONTENT_P1, PAGE_CONTENT_P2, ....PAGE_CONTENT_Pnth? That seems wrong to me.

So how do I set up my stringbuilder so that the text is broken up in paragraphs?

Here is how I have it now. Please let me know if there is any other code you need to see. Thanks

```
sb.Append("<h1 class=\"title\">" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PAGE_TITLE"].ToString() + "</h1> ");
sb.Append("<div class=\"row\">");
sb.Append("<div class=\"col-md-12 history\">");
sb.Append("<p class=\"text-justify\">" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PAGE_CONTENT"].ToString() + "</p> ");
sb.Append("</div>");
sb.Append("</div>");
```

Comment: Is it your intent to allow HTML within the database column? Can the content be modified to included placeholders that you will replace with HTML, e.g. `{br}` would become a line break, for output?

Comment: That could probably work in this particular case but if I was allowing the client to change this content with a CMS I doubt the client will be inserting <br> after paragraphs. So I kind of need it to be able to respect the paragraph format both in and out of the database. But for now, I am just worrying about going out from the DB in paragraphs

Comment: What delimits paragraphs now? `\r\n\r\n`?  That can be what you change into suitable HTML. What you want to avoid is accidentally allowing HTML in the text to be output without being HTML encoded. That's a common source of injection attacks.

Comment: How are you saving data in your DB? Does the user edit this an RTF and save as plain text? Or are you preserving the original editing format?

Comment: As it is now the text is in plain text, one big paragraph. No delimiters. Maybe that's what I need? I'm not sure. I'm not so worried yet about how the user will be injecting text in the database. I will later tho. But for now, I want to learn what is the proper way to store and display the page content in several paragraphs

Comment: If you already have a `<p>` at the beginning and `</p>` tag at the end, why not just replace `"\n"` with `"</p><p class=\"text-justify\">"`?

Comment: A CMS is something that I will be interested in later. But for now, the content doesn't have the ability to be changed yet. Just stored dynamically in a DB

Comment: If it was not clear, I meant: why not translate on the way out? Add a `.Replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"text-justify\">")` after the `["PAGE_CONTENT"].ToString()`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: So it looks like a big paragraph because it is one. Strange. Once you decide what the paragraph separator should be, the procedure is fairly simple. _(Assuming that you do not intend to allow HTML content in the database.)_ Split the string on the paragraph separator, HTML encode each segment, then wrap each segment in paragraph tags. Output the result without HTML encoding.

Comment: Thanks HABO. But srutzky knows what I'm talking about.

Comment: @srutzky That worked! Please add as an answer, I'd like to give you credit for this. Plus others can learn as well. Thanks again

Comment: If you just do a straight replacement of text in the string with HTML tags then you can't HTML encode the output. That means that any HTML pieces in the original string, e.g. a bit of evil script, will be output. It also means that the original string must already have HTML encoded values for things like ampersand characters.

Comment: @HABO does make a good point. That is probably a more flexible approach. So what is appropriate? Should we both add answers, that way HABO can maybe give a brief code example? At the very least I should include that in my answer, giving proper credit, of course.

Comment: @HABO I see what you are saying. When you put it that way. That's why I was more interested in the best way to this altogether. I see you guys added answers. I'm very interested to go over them . So I better get to it now :)

Comment: I don't think @HABO posted an answer yet, but I included that method as an alternate suggestion in mine. I will say that while it does allow for more flexibility, it does not seem materially different than what I was suggesting, at least with regards to the stated concern of not being able to HTML encode. As I show in my answer, you just HTML encode the content first, and _then_ replace the newline characters; it's a simple matter of which operation is done first.

Comment: @srutzky I commented on your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the current code, one option would be to simplistically just replace the newline characters (already in the content) on the way out.

The current line already includes beginning and ending `<p>` tags:

```
sb.Append("<p class=\"text-justify\">" + ... + "</p> ");
```

So, the easiest thing to do would be to translate newlines into closing and beginning tags (i.e. `</p><p>`):

```
...["PAGE_CONTENT"].ToString().Replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"text-justify\">")
```

Of course, it might be safer to prevent malicious, embedded HTML / scripting by first HTML encoding the content:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(
     ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PAGE_CONTENT"].ToString()
  ).Replace("\n", "</p><p class=\"text-justify\">")
```

And, the most flexible method, as suggested by @HABO in a comment on the question, is to do something like the following:

```
sb.AppendLine("<div class=\"col-md-12 history\">");
foreach(string _Paragraph in
          ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["PAGE_CONTENT"].ToString().Split(new Char[] {'\n'}))
{
  sb.AppendLine("<p class=\"text-justify\">");
  sb.AppendLine(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_Paragraph));
  sb.AppendLine("</p>");
}
sb.AppendLine("</div>");
```

Comment: I added the last part of the code. I got an error: an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'system.web.httpserverutility.htmlencode(string)

Comment: @LOTUSMS Try changing `HttpServerUtility` to be just `HttpUtility`, and if that doesn't work, change it to `WebUtility`.

Comment: HttpUtility worked. I don't understand it, but it worked. I will dig deeper in this you helped me out with. I don't want to do it mechanically, I want to understand it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

```
<div style="width:500px;height:150px;overflow-y: scroll;">... your long text </div>
```

try this , use it, if it is help

Comment: I'm sorry @Mudeyanse but adding a scroll to content is not the right way to go and not very aesthetic. Not to mention I specified I wan to break my paragraph into several paragraphs. this doesn't do that